# Cant get MSMQ to work properly

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I keep receiving an error when i try to Send to the queues

**The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.**

My queue name is stored in a config file and looks like this

"FormatName:Direct=OS:MyComputerName\PRIVATE$\MyQueue"

There are 2 queues that exist, each queue has permissions set so that EVERYONE has Full Control.

SyncUser you can assume  = "EVERYONE" or "My_Domain\operator"

```
//init the queues
qSync = new MessageQueue(queueName + "-sync")
            {Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] {typeof (String)})};

qClient = new MessageQueue(queueName + "-client")
            {Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) })};
```

Creating the queues doesn't cause any errors, but I receive errors when i call this Send function

```
**Send(qSync, "This is a message");** //Example

public void Send(MessageQueue queue, string msg)
{
    try
    {
        queue.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (MessageQueueException mqx)
    {
        var e = string.Format("Failed to Send - {0} | {1}", queue.QueueName, mqx.Message);
        OnSynchronizerMonitor(new SyncEvent(e));
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

It seems that my messages **ARE** making it to their remote queue destination, but the application is still throwing that error on every message sent. If I look at the MessageQueues (qSync|qClient) while debugging, that error shows up in several of the inner fields, before it is even used.

Comment: Are you trying to send to a remote machine? Does everything work if everything is running on the local machine? Also are your queues transactional?

Comment: Yes it is a remote machine, the Slave will run locally and it seems to run fine, but all it does it read from the queue, so at the moment it hasn't been well tested. And it is a non-transactional queue

Comment: You're calling Queue.Send() but you've not shown how Queue is set up.

Comment: Apologies, the code has been updated. 'queue' is whatever queue gets passed into the function. I did this because i have multiple queues that utilize the same Send logic.

Comment: Are you sure that a PRIVATE queue could be reached from a remote machine? I'd say this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone can confirm this for me as I cant seem to find any forum questions or documentation that support this, but it seems that the MessageQueue has an issue with my Event setup.

**I removed the event call and simply hardcoded the queue creation and send in its place within my main process and everything worked fine.**

My setup is like so:

A Service - Creates a Processor, a Synchronizer, and sets the events.

Processor starts a **thread** in which it processes string transactions, on a successful process the transaction needs to be sent via the Synchronizer, so the Processor triggers event.

Synchronizer has already created the queues and is simply waiting for events to be triggered to send messages.

If anyone could shed some light on if this could be a cross thread issue or just a quirk in my system it would be appreciated.

****After a little more research and some trial and error, it seems I get the error due to a cross thread complication with the event. My guess is that it's a similar issue to UI objects being updated from a different thread than the one it was created on. The error is essentially an ownership issue. The messages still go though but the queue complains that its original owner isn't the one that initiated the call.**